# Mypy can't infer the type of items from a list of Literals

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I have a variable `x` and a list of literals (say 0, 1, 2). I want to convert `x` to one of those literals: if `x` is in the list, I return it; otherwise I return a fallback value:

```py
from typing import Literal, Set

Foo = Literal[0, 1, 2]
foos: Set[Foo] = {0, 1, 2}
 
def convert_to_foo(x: int) -> Foo:
  if x in foos:
    # x must have type Foo, yet this doesn't type check
    y: Foo = x
    return y
  return 0
```

Unfortunately, this does not type check. Mypy returns the following message (see [gist](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=a1f06a82aa90bf22416d53cff048030f)):

```
main.py:9: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "Union[Literal[0], Literal[1], Literal[2]]")
```

If I belong to a list of `Foo`s, then I am a `Foo`, right? I can't find an answer in the doc, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think mypy can deduce that `x` is a `Foo` just because it belongs to a `Set[Foo]`. What if a set subclass overrode the `__contains__` method to always return true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent question. I *think* that `cast` might be the only way to go here:

```py
from typing import Literal, Set, cast

Foo = Literal[0, 1, 2]
foos: Set[Foo] = {0, 1, 2}
 
def convert_to_foo(x: int) -> Foo:
    if x in foos:
        y: Foo = cast(Foo, x)
        return y
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code on windows Python3.8 and did not find any problem.

```
from typing import Literal, Set

Foo = Literal[0, 1, 2]
foos: Set[Foo] = {0, 1, 2}

def convert_to_foo(x: int) -> Foo:
    if x in foos:
        # x must have type Foo, yet this doesn't type check
        y: Foo = x
        print(y)
        return y
    return 0

>>> convert_to_foo(3)
0
>>> convert_to_foo(2)
2
2
```

**what exactly do you want to do? Here it checks if for 3 and returns 0 for 2 returns 2.
Is not that what you check for?**

Comment: It is a typing problem in mypy. If you don't know mypy, check the docs https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Exactly, the problem is with Mypy static typing, not with the code itself. See the error yourself here: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=a1f06a82aa90bf22416d53cff048030f

Answer (score 0):

I tried this `x:Any, default: int`

```
from typing import Literal, Set
from typing import *

Foo = Literal[0, 1, 2]
foos: Set[Foo] = {0, 1, 2}

def convert_to_foo(x:Any, default: int) -> Foo:
  if x in foos:
    # x must have type Foo, yet this doesn't type check
    y: Foo = x
    return y
  return 0
```

**Success: no issues found in 1 source file**

Comment: Unfortunately, using `Any` more or less turns off the type checker (from [the doc](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dynamic_typing.html#operations-on-any-values): '_You can do anything using a value with type `Any`, and type checker does not complain_'), so we're losing the benefits of static typing. Thanks for the effort though